# How to loop through indexed symbolics Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

so what im trying to do is to refer to different symbolics by indexing as you would with a vector

```
syms k_1 k_2 k_3 
for i= 1:3
    'expression to get k_i'
end
```

Desired answer would be k1 k2 k3.

I do not intend to do this with a vector created by the `sym` function unless there's a way to assign a matrix to a vector position without getting this error

[image: error message].

Comment: We would need a [mcve] to verify why you're getting that error, but it looks like something unrelated to it being a symbolic variable

Comment: "How to loop symbolics in a loop"...? Of course a loop loops, do you mean a loop within another loop, i.e. a nested loop?

Comment: Sorry about the title hehe, no i meant what wolfie answered below. How to use a loop’s index to access multiple variables that are listed with a subindex such as k1 k2 and k3. I’ll make sure to change it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add them all to a struct, then use dynamic referencing to the ith field name:

```
% Create symbolic vars
syms k_1 k_2 k_3
% Assign to struct
K.k_1 = k_1;
K.k_2 = k_2;
K.k_3 = k_3;
% Loop through 
for ii = 1:3
    kstr = sprintf('k_%d', ii); % = 'k_1', 'k_2', ...
    ki = K.(kstr);              % equivalent to ki = K.k_1 etc
end
```

Equivalently, once you have the struct you can just use the field names, although it's a bit less explicit which field you're accessing each iteration.

```
f = fieldnames(K);
for ii = 1:numel(f)
    ki = K.(f{ii});
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to @Wolfie's answer, you can use a cell array:

```matlab
syms k_1 k_2 k_3
k = {k_1, k_2, k_3};
for ii = 1:3
    ki = k{ii};
end
```

This is somewhat simpler than the `struct` solution, but doesn't preserve the variable names. In this case, `k{1}` is similar enough to `k_1`, so maybe this doesn't matter.